# Slot and referring template in the same component in parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am stuck with a problem in vue 2. Basically I have a parent and child component. Basically I want to do something like this.

Parent.vue:

```
<template>
 <div>
 <Child>
   <template #MyComponent>
      <slot name="MyComponent" />
   </template>
 </Child>
  <template #MyComponent>
     <MyComponent/>
   </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Child.vue:

```
   <template>
     <slot name="myComponent"/>
   </template>
```

Can this be done in vue? I have tried to do this. But it doesn't refer to the `MyComponent`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Parent.vue` template does not make sense. Specifically the `<template #MyComponent>` adjacent to `<Child>`.

Comment: I have added a `<div>` . Basically I want to refer the `MyComponent` slot outside the child component scope. This is not right way to do it. I want to do something like this where I can refer it in the `parent.vue`

Comment: Can you show how `Parent.vue` would theoretically use the slot (assuming this template syntax were valid)?

Comment: theoretically this won't work. I need something that will work. I just need to refer the `myComponent` inside the child component using anything. This doesn't have to be slot. Hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not, how the structure of slots work. You are calling `<template #MyComponent>` outside of your `<Child>` and trying to do something there, that is hard to understand.

I´ll asume you try to pass a component named `MyComponent` inside of the slot of another component named `Child`. This is a small example for this case:

```
// Parent, where you call your Child with myComponent in the slot
<Child>
   <template #mySlot>
      <my-component></my-component>
   </template>
</Child>

// Child
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="mySlot"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

// myComponent
<template>
  <div>
    Text from myComponent.vue
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I know the structure of slot doesn't work like that. I just need something that can refer the `my-component` inside of parent component but outside of the child scope. 
thanks for the help

Comment: @Ragib For what purpose?

Comment: well I have a `component` that will be used in two different child components. But the child component has some logic that is rendering two different `component` in my application. For that it is creating some problem.

Comment: Okay, I still can´t imagine what´s the goal. Can you provide code of the child with the logic? Maybe there is a different approach.